# Understanding PayPal Express Checkout flow

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use PP Express Checkout Flow on my website to sell items through PayPal and I use this [wizard](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/), but I have some doubts around the process itself. I'll explain what I did and then ask for doubts.

1. Pick "Express Checkout PayPal"
2. Setup parameters by setting: PHP as language, return_url as Return URL, cancel_url as Cancel URL and leave the rest as they are
3. Then in "Step 2. Add PayPal to your shopping cart page" the wizard generates two files "expresscheckout.php" and "paypalfunctions.php" I did what they said there about download files and setup the rest like API Username and API Password among others
4. Review the code in "Step 3. Add PayPal to your billing page (payment option)" and download the code to integrate later in my application
5. Review the code in "Step 4. Order Review - get shipping address from PayPal" and download the code to integrate later in my application
6. Review the code in "Step 5. Order Confirmation - confirm payment from PayPal" and download the code to integrate later in my application

Now in `expresscheckout.php` they call the method `CallShortcutExpressCheckout()` which call inside `SetExpressCheckout`. With just that piece of code and without doing anything with code from point 4, 5 and 6 step the application redirects to PayPal and aparently did something in Sandbox but when I call the method `GetExpressCheckoutDetails()` I get `PaymentActionNotInitiated` in `CHECKOUTSTATUS` so transaction wasn't made. Then,

1. What did I miss in the process?
2. Should I add a billing step, an order review and an order confirmation step to my payment flow?
3. Why does `SetExpressCheckout` guide me through PayPal directly and not through the wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has a diagram that may help you visualize how the flow was intended to work: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/ it illustrates 3 API calls, the SetExpressCheckout is called to set up the transaction and define the URL to which the customer is returned after the customer authorizes payment. The GetExpressCheckoutDetails call to get customer shipping info so you can calculate tax and shipping information to display to customer for final approval. Then, DoExpressCheckoutPayment is called to complete the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, after the `setexprescheckout` you need to do [DoExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) in order to complete the payment.

Comment: Yes but how that fits in my code, I mean should I create a step by step wizard or how to get this done?